# WPF: How to call a method at a specific point in time while an animation is running

Tags: wpf, animation

My problem is the following:

I've got an animation which makes a panel slide until it disappears (I animate its margin property). As soon as the animation ends, I want the panel to go back where it was at the start. So I set the autoreverse property to true, animation duration doubles automaticly, and everithing runs fine. Problem is I'm still missing something fundamental in my program: when the animation has run midway, that is when the panel disappears, I have to do some processing, calling a method, which makes the panel content change its UI.
So, is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using timers that start at the beginning of the animation .....

Comment: You could simplify things: don't use autoreverse. Devide your animation in 2 parts: 1) slide in, then do your UI changes, 2) slide out

Comment: That's what I do right now, I hope there was something more streamlined

Comment: How are you creating the animations? Through storyboards?

Comment: yes, cause really I have to move 2 panels in unison

Comment: Is the storyboard created with xaml or in the code-behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deafjeff suggests, you could make 2 animation instead of using autoreverse. Register a handler for the `Completed` event for the first animation. Do the UI changes and start 2nd animation in the hanlder code. Code is like followig:

```
private void onFirstAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DoUIChange();
  SecondAnimation.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I've said this is what I do, I asked this question, cause I would have liked to spare an animation.

Comment: You can still wrap the two animations in a `Storyboard`, and register the `Completed EventHandler` for the slide in animation. If you stick to your "autoreverse" approch, you may use a `DispatcherTimer` to arrange the update ui code at any time you want, but I don't think it is a neat solution.